# displaying duplicate shipping methods in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, php-5.4, shipping-methods

I'm writing this question of previous [thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25619/problem-with-displaying-shipping-method), it's displaying duplicate shipping methods.

When I create `system.log` it's appending correctly but in my website displaying duplicate shipping method.

**my log file:**

```
2014-07-02T08:49:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [carrier] => msmultiflat
            [method] => msmultiflat
            [carrier_title] => Major
            [method_title] => Test 2
            [price] => 0
            [cost] => 
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
    [_origData:protected] => 
    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)

2014-07-02T08:49:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): End.....
2014-07-02T08:49:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [carrier] => msmultiflat
            [method] => msmultiflat
            [carrier_title] => Major2
            [method_title] => Test 3
            [price] => 0
            [cost] => 
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
    [_origData:protected] => 
    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)

2014-07-02T08:49:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): End.....
2014-07-02T08:49:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [carrier] => msmultiflat
            [method] => msmultiflat
            [carrier_title] => Major2
            [method_title] => Test 4
            [price] => 0
            [cost] => 
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
    [_origData:protected] => 
    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)

2014-07-02T08:49:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): End.....
```

**Duplicate shipping methods**

```
Custom Shipping
1) Test 4 $0.00
2) Test 4 $0.00
3) Test 4 $0.00 

Flat Rate
2) Fixed $0.00
```

**Required format**

```
Custom Shipping

Major
1) Test 1 $0.00

Major2
1) Test 3 $0.00
2) Test 4 $0.00 

Flat Rate
1) Fixed $0.00
```

**Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?**

or

**How can I do this? any suggestions/idea it will be great,**

Thanks.

Comment: please write the reason before down vote? it will be better to improve the skills. I'm asking not only for me for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved.

my code is:

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {

        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $handling = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/handling');
        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

        $results = $this->getConfigData('name');
        $results_one = split(',',$results);
        foreach($results_one as $one){
            switch($one)
            {
                case 'test1' :
                    $name = 'Test 1';
                    $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
                    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
                    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
                    $method->setCarrierTitle('Major');
                    $method->setMethodTitle($name);
                    $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
                    $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('price'));
                    $result->append($method);
                    break;
                case 'test2' :
                    $name = 'Test 2';
                    $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
                    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
                    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
                    $method->setCarrierTitle('Major');
                    $method->setMethodTitle($name);
                    $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
                    $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('price'));
                    $result->append($method);
                    break;
                case 'test3' :
                    $name = 'Test 3';
                    $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
                    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
                    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
                    $method->setCarrierTitle('Major2');
                    $method->setMethodTitle($name);
                    $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
                    $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('price'));
                    $result->append($method);
                    break;
                case 'test4' :
                    $name = 'Test 4';
                    $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
                    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
                    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
                    $method->setCarrierTitle('Major2');
                    $method->setMethodTitle($name);
                    $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
                    $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('price'));
                    $result->append($method);
                    break;
            }

        }


        return $result;

    }
```

//config.xml

```
..
 <frontend>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <msmultiflat>
                    <file>msmultiflat.xml</file>
                </msmultiflat>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
..
```

//layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">

        <reference name='checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available'>
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <template>shippings/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>


        <!-- <reference name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method">
             <action method="setTemplate">
                 <template>shippings/onepage/shipping_method.phtml</template>
             </action>
         </reference>-->

    </checkout_onepage_index>

    <checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>
        <reference name='root'>
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <template>shippings/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_shippingmethod>


</layout>
```

//available.phtml

```
<?php
$a=0;
$b=0;
?>
<?php $_shippingRateGroups = $this->getShippingRates(); ?>
<?php if (!$_shippingRateGroups): ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <dl class="sp-methods">
        <?php $shippingCodePrice = array(); ?>
        <?php $_sole = count($_shippingRateGroups) == 1; foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
            <dt>
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?>

            </dt>
            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <?php $_sole = $_sole && count($_rates) == 1; foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                        <?php $shippingCodePrice[] = "'".$_rate->getCode()."':".(float)$_rate->getPrice(); ?>
                        <li>
                            <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <ul class="messages">
                                    <li class="error-msg">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php if ($_sole) : ?>
                                    <span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio"
                                         value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"
                                         id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"
                                         checked="checked" /></span>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php

                                 $method_name = $_rate->getMethodTitle();
                                if($method_name == "Test 1" || $method_name == "Test 2"){
                                    if($a == 0  ){
                                        echo $this->escapeHtml('Major') ;
                                        $a++;
                                    }
                                    echo '<p/>';
                                }
                                if($method_name == "Test 3" || $method_name == "Test 4"){
                                    if($b == 0 ){
                                        echo $this->escapeHtml('Major 2') ;
                                        $b++;
                                    }
                                    echo '<p/>';
                                }

                                ?>
                                <input name="shipping_method" type="radio"
                                       value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"
                                       id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio"/>

                                <?php if ($_rate->getCode() === $this->getAddressShippingMethod()): ?>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        //<![CDATA[
                                        lastPrice = <?php echo (float)$_rate->getPrice(); ?>;
                                        //]]>
                                    </script>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                                    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                    <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                        (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </label>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        <?php if (!empty($shippingCodePrice)): ?>
        var shippingCodePrice = {<?php echo implode(',',$shippingCodePrice); ?>};
        <?php endif; ?>

        $$('input[type="radio"][name="shipping_method"]').each(function(el){
            Event.observe(el, 'click', function(){
                if (el.checked == true) {
                    var getShippingCode = el.getValue();
                    <?php if (!empty($shippingCodePrice)): ?>
                    var newPrice = shippingCodePrice[getShippingCode];
                    if (!lastPrice) {
                        lastPrice = newPrice;
                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += newPrice;
                    }
                    if (newPrice != lastPrice) {
                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += (newPrice-lastPrice);
                        lastPrice = newPrice;
                    }
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```